# how to ssh in Openstack instance

Tags: openstack

I create Fedora instance in horizon by giving public key. But i didn't get any user and password to ssh the instance. Also tried to create instance from shell by running this,

```
nova boot --config-drive=true --flavor 3 --key-name testkey --image be1437b9-b7b4-4e56-a2c3-f92cdd0848ce --user-data cloud-config.txt test
```

Instance launched successfully in both case and when i try to login with root it ask me for password.

So please tell me what is the exact way to create a fedora instance in Openstack and what would be its user and password for ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let leave cloud-init option in nova boot, I have also tried this one,

```
nova boot --flavor 3 --key-name testkey --image be1437b9-b7b4-4e56-a2c3-f92cdd0848ce test
```

In this command Instance launches successfully, but still I can't ssh the instance.

Where as now when I create instance from horizon I do ssh in that instance easily.

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm, I suppose that you have the corresponding .pem file for the keyname that you create (testkey) and this file has the appropriate permissions to be used to access using ssh. I mean chmod 600 of the .pem file.

If this is the case, you should go into the instance only executing the following sentence:

```
ssh -i testkey.pem root@<IP address>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed cloud-init package from epel repository?

So, you can get into the server using 'fedora' or 'cloud-user' user account.

http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/ch_obtaining_images.html

Answer (score 0):

For the first time login it is recommended that you generate a key-pair (In ubuntu, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) and inject into the image (http://docs.openstack.org/grizzly/basic-install/yum/content/basic-install_operate.html) and do SSH to the instance using the key-pair. Once you are logged in, you can create a user and using this user you can login through VNC console.